# How to divide BigInt by decimal in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal, bigint

I have this code below:

```js
let n = 100n;
let x = 0.1;

console.log(n/x); // Throws error
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions
```

How do I divide a `BigInt` by a decimal value in JavaScipt?

Comment: What result do you want? I mean, it's fairly obvious with the specific two values you've mentioned, but with other values it would be a lot less clear. A BigInt? A number? If a BigInt, what do you want to do with the fractional portion of the result (when there is one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In general...

...mixing `number` and `BigInt` is asking for trouble, which is why no math operators will let you do it and explicit conversion is required.

(Note: [`Decimal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decimal) is on the horizon, which will apply here when it matures.)

### If you want a `number` result...

...convert the `BigInt` to a `number` before doing the calculation; beware that the conversion **may be lossy** for very large numbers (this is the point of `BigInt`), specifically numbers above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` or below `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`:

```js
let n = 100n;
let x = 0.1;
let result = Number(n) / x;
console.log(result);
```

#### If you want a `BigInt` result...

...it's more complicated, because you have to decide what to do with a fractional result. (Your example won't have a fractional result, but the general case will.) You could go through `number`, but again that's a potentially lossy operation:

```js
let n = 100n;
let x = 0.1;
let result = BigInt(Number(n) / x); // Throws if the result is fractional
// let result = BigInt(Math.round(Number(n) / x)); // Rounds instead of throwing
console.log(result.toString());
```

If you can refactor the operation so you can express it in whole numbers, that makes it a lot easier, because then you can make `x` a `BigInt`. For instance, in your *specific* case, `/ 0.1` is the same as `* (1 / 0.1)` which is `* 10`:

```js
let n = 100n;
let x = 10n;
let result = n * x;
console.log(result.toString());
```

...but that's just that specific case.

You'll probably find you need to handle it on a case-by-case basis, trying to avoid doing the operation. When you can't, and the divisor is fractional, a round-trip through `number` may be unavoidable.

Answer (score -1):

Just Convert the bigint to number. It will Work.

```
let n = 100n;
let x = 0.1;
console.log(Number(n)/x);
```

It will Return Result 1000

Comment: ...unless of course the `BigInt` is out of the safe integer range, which is the whole point of `BigInt`.